# QToolbar on mac could not be unified even after setting setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac flag

Tags: python, macos, qt, pyqt

This is a Mac OS QT issue,

I have created a QMainWindow and added a toolbar to it.

after setting "**setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac**" flag to TRUE my toolbar got unified to my mainwindow.

But **when i customize the window buttons** such as only close button option,

my window **Toolbar got detached from title bar** as if it looks like a winodow OS toolbar

not like a Mac native one.

Attached my test code below which is in pyqt.

Hope someone know how to achieve it.

Thanks

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class Ui_windo(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setObjectName("windo")
        self.resize(400, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("window", "window", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

        self.b1 = QtGui.QToolButton()
        self.b1.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextOnly)
        self.b1.setText('Test')
        self.b1.setObjectName("b1")
        self.b1.setCheckable(True)

        _toolBar = self.addToolBar('test')
        _toolBar.setMovable(False)
        _toolBar.addWidget(self.b1)
        self.setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac(True);
        _windowButtons = QtCore.Qt.Window| QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint
        self.setWindowFlags(_windowButtons)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Ui_windo()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the `Qt.CustomizeWindowHint` flag removes the styling from the toolbar. Not sure if this is expected behavior or a bug. There have been a number of style-related bug reports pertaining to `setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac`. You should post it to confirm whether its expected or not.

https://bugreports.qt-project.org/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa

If you set your window flag to use `Qt.Tool`, that will at least get you close by removing the minimize button.